# Are coins used for anything other than Plant Food and Power-Ups?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-2

In Plants vs Zombies 1, you used coins to purchase new plants, upgrades and the like, whereas Plants vs Zombies 2 appears to only use real money in its store. Instead, as far as I can tell by going through the first bit of the game, coins are only used for Plant Food and Power-Ups.

Are coins used for anything else during the rest of the game, or can I safely use my coins on Plant Food and Power-Ups instead of hoarding them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Per the official [Support page](http://support.popcap.com/pvz2) (click on the "How do I get more coins?" question):

> You'll use the Coins to purchase extra Plant Food and Power Ups!

That's all they are used for.

Comment: I hoarded the coins until I hit a wall on gaining stars then I used the coins liberally to pass the frustrating levels. It mainly to decapitate zombies.

Comment: In addition to that (guess that didn't exist at the time this answer was wrote) you can use coins to retry failed [Piñata Parties](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Pi%C3%B1ata_Party).

Answer (score 2):

I noticed recently that later in the game you can also spend coins to level up your plants and some plants can be bought with coins from crazy daves shop (also known as twiddydinkies.)